# Right-click context menu for Clickpad

Tags: touchpad

I have an HP Stream 14 with a large clickpad. Previously, when I had Windows 10, the clickpad had a right-click context menu when clicking the right side of the clickpad. I can't seem to get that working for me... any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question with the execution result / output of `apt list --installed | grep "xserver-xorg-input-libinput"`. Simply edit your question with what you see after executing this command in terminal. 
If you don't see anything after executing the command, please execute `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and let me know if this fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have The Same Issue But Go Here For A Fix  https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5h1y4k/eos_on_hp_stream_14/

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to include the answer here and leave the source link. Have a nice day!